# issue with exporting animated objects in fbx format

Tags: export, .fbx

I want to export a simple animated object without armature (only two frames) as fbx into PowerPoint. I know PowerPoint supports fbx but when I import fbx from blender into PowerPoint it only shows the object and not animation.
could someone help me to resolve this issue? I really need animated object in PowerPoint for my presentation.

Comment: IDK about powerpoint and fbx, but if it's just 2 poses, why not render them?

Comment: but I need the object as 3D in powerpoint. If I render it, it would be a video format. am I right? could you explain more about rendering?

Comment: You could just render 2 frames as images, save them and use PPt to show them consecutively. If you plan on rotating the scene during your presentation, this won't work. Explanation for rendering: Too large a topic to cover it here, search for it on Youtube, lots of stuff there.